# No puedo mostrar los atributos - Undefined property: stdClass::$categoria

Tags: eloquent, laravel-7

Estoy intentando mostrar el contenido de dos tablas relacionadas, pero creo que no logro hacer la relación correctamente.
Tengo 2 tablas, **categorias** y **productos**. La tabla **categorias**, contiene los campos **id_cat** y **nom_cat**. Uno de los campos de la tabla **productos** es **cat_prod**, que almacena lo mismo que el campo **id_cat**, obvio, siendo la id de la categoria a la que pertenece el producto. Ninguno de estos modelos los he migrado con comandos, pero los creé directamente en phpMyAdmin, y hasta ahora no sé si esto me genera problemas.

Este es el modelo de **Categoria**:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Categoria extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;
    const UPDATED_AT = null;
    const CREATED_AT = null;
    protected $primaryKey = "id_cat";
    public $fillable = ['nom_cat'];
    public $incrementing = false;
    public $timestamps = false;
}
```

Y este es el modelo de **Producto**:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Producto extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;
    const UPDATED_AT = null;
    const CREATED_AT = null;
    protected $primaryKey = "id_prod";
    public $fillable = ['nom_prod'];
    public $incrementing = false;
    public $timestamps = false;


    //Aqui intento hacer la relacion para tener acceso al atributo NOMBRE de la categoria correspondiente//

    public function categoria(){
        return $this->hasOne(Categoria::class, 'id_cat', 'cat_prod');
    }
}
```

Hecho esto, intento mostrar en pantalla el atributo **nom_cat**

```
<tbody>
    @foreach ($productos as $prod)
        <tr>
            <td class="body-td">{{$prod->id_prod}}</td>
            <td class="body-td">{{$prod->nom_prod}}</td>
            <td class="body-td"></td>
            <td class="body-td">{{$prod->categoria->nom_cat}}</td> //Esta linea genera el error//
            <td class="body-td"></td>
            <td class="body-td"></td>
            <td class="body-td"></td>
            <td class="body-td"></td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
</tbody>
```

Si quito esa linea, me muestra bien lo demás, pero no he podido solucionar este error

**Undefined property: stdClass::$categoria**

Esta es la consulta con la que obtengo los atributos de la tabla **producto**:

```
public function getProductos(){
        $productos = DB::table('productos')->select('*')
        ->whereNull('deleted_at')
        ->get();
        return view('admin.productos.home', compact('productos'));
    }
```

Respecto a esta consulta, puedo mostrar sin ningún problema los datos obtenidos.

Y según el video que estoy siguiendo, con este codigo basta para obtener los datos que quiero mostrar:

```
//Aqui intento hacer la relacion para tener acceso al atributo NOMBRE de la categoria correspondiente//
public function categoria(){
    return $this->hasOne(Categoria::class, 'id_cat', 'cat_prod');
}
```

(Ya hice referencia a este fragmento de código más arriba)

¿Qué error estoy cometiendo?¿Como puedo resolverlo?

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Algunas veces ese error es por que no trae ningún dato, ahi donde tienes "@foreach ($productos as $prod)" arribita hazle un dd: `@php dd($productos); @endphp` y mira si te esta trayendo los datos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema se genera por que tu consulta la estás construyendo a partir del *facade* `DB` y el método `categoria` solo existe en la clase modelo `Producto`, misma clase que no empleas.

Si necesitas obtener la categoría asociada a los productos y por ende acceder a su nombre entonces la consulta podría quedar de esta forma:

```
Producto::with('categoria')->whereNull('deleted_at')->get();
```

De ese modo, podrás acceder a la categoría por medio de *eager loading*, recomiendo repases el tema de [*eloquent relationships*](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships)

Comment: Muchas gracias! Cambié mi consulta por la que me aconsejaste y solucionó de inmediato mi problema